# CodeAcademy Median exercise in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am going through Codeacademy and doing the exercises in Python 3 as well. I am having trouble getting good output on the "Median" exercise.

I'm getting the error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float.

I have tried converting the indexes to floats. I cannot use floor division (`//`) because I need a non-integer to be returned as the result.

```
def median(lst):
    sorted_list = sorted(lst)
    if len(sorted_list) % 2 != 0:
        index = len(sorted_list)//2
        return sorted_list[index]
    elif len(sorted_list) % 2 == 0:
        index_1 = (len(sorted_list)/2)
        index_2 = (len(sorted_list)/2) - 1
        mean = (sorted_list[index_1] + sorted_list[index_2])/2
        return mean

print(median([1, 6, 5, 47, 3, 100, 59, 36, 4, 38]))
```

Any help from the gurus would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use (//) for index_1 and index_2. your result will be floating because for mean use (/)

Answer (score 0):

The index of an item in a list is its position within the list.

```
example_list = [1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 9]
```

Here, if you want the median value you should be averaging the two middle values: 4 and 5. If you're doing this by finding the `len(example_list) / 2` and taking that as an index, your index is not an integer, so it doesn't point to a position in the list.

What is the `3.0` position of something? It doesn't make sense. You need to use integers only when taking slices. In your case:

```
elif len(sorted_list) % 2 == 0:
    index_1 = (len(sorted_list) // 2)
    index_2 = (len(sorted_list) // 2) - 1
    mean = (sorted_list[index_1] + sorted_list[index_2]) / 2
    return mean
```

Edit:

Whenever you use `/` Your answer will be a float. Even if the result is an integer mathematically, it will be returned as `x.0` not `x`.